# Cancel all pending Kotlin jobs from ViewModel's onCleared

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions, coroutinescope

With Kotlin 1.3 one can launch job using `GlobalScope.launch` but one thing that  I can't seem to figure out is how to keep track of `Job` returned by ``GlobalScope.launch` and cancel all pending jobs if they are active.

In older version of `launch` one could specify `parent = parentJob` and one could simply cancel parentJob. But when using `GlobalScope.launch` how does one cancel all pending jobs (easily) so from say ViewModel's onCleared one can cancel all pending stuff.

Comment: The answer is that you should not use `GlobalScope.launch`. You must define your own scope.

Answer (score 3):

So basically it turns out you can either have your ViewModel/AppComptActivity etc. inherit from CoroutineScope. Or you can use composition like this:

```

```
private val pendingJobs = Job()
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(contextProvider.io + pendingJobs)

...
...

    coroutineScope.launch  {

    withContext(contextProvider.UI) {

    }
    }
```

```

Then in appropriate destroy method call `pendingJobs.cancel()` to terminate pending jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GlobalScope` is highly discouraged. In the [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) libraries there are handy scopes that can be used to launch coroutines. Using them you don't need to think about cancelling jobs, they designed to do it by themselves. `CoroutineScope`s:

- In `ViewModel` class it is [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#viewmodel). The `CoroutineScope` is bound to `Dispatchers.Main` and is automatically cancelled when the `ViewModel` is cleared. You can use `viewModelScope` instead of creating a new scope for each `ViewModel`.
  Dependency:

  ```
  implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
  ```
- In `Activity`/`Fragment` there is [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#lifecycle). Any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the `Lifecycle` is destroyed. You can access the `CoroutineScope` of the `Lifecycle` by using the `lifecycle.coroutineScope` or `lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` properties.
  Dependency:

  ```
  implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
  ```

Example of launching a coroutine in `ViewModel`:

```
viewModelScope.launch {...}
```